# Add top and left borders with magick command

Tags: imagemagick

Is there a way to add 5 or any number of white/transparent pixels at the top and left borders of an image with the magick command in Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [-splice](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#splice) operator. First make a solid magenta rectangle:

```
magick -size 100x50 xc:magenta image.png
```

Now splice on a yellow chunk (so you can see it) 10 wide and 20 tall:

```
magick image.png -background yellow -gravity northwest -splice 10x20 result.png
```

[image]

Change `yellow` to `none` for transparent pixels.

Change `magick` to `convert` for v6 **ImageMagick**.

---

If you just want to splice to the East side:

```
magick image.png -background yellow -gravity east -splice 10x east.png
```

[image]

---

If you just want to splice to the South side:

```
magick image.png -background yellow -gravity south -splice x10 south.png
```

[image]